# Disabling click on minute cell

Tags: jquery, html, css

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/workdreamer/vrW2n/2/)

i have html table and one textbox and one button.make cell selection by dragging on cell .on click of button i am getting value of textbox and put into span tag of cell. i have to disble click on minute cell 0,15,30,45. In fiddle u see when i click on minute cell then it makes css green and css length is incremented (those chking in alert).

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here. Are you trying to make it so that the mousedown event fires but the click event does not?

Comment: In fiddle u see when i click on minute cell then it makes css green and css length is incremented (those chking in alert).So i have to disable click on minute cell

Comment: Yes that is what the code you have is supposed to do. Is it not supposed to do that?

Comment: the functionality code remains same but only difference that when i click on minute cell then it makes css green and css length is incremented so i have to do not increment css length after click on minute cell if increment of css length then alert popups so i have to avoid increment

Comment: @Nikhil Tell me about what you want to accomplish, not your errors. It's so confused

Comment: @void:when i click on minute cell then it makes css green and css length is incremented so i have avoid that nothing else

Comment: This has to be the most confusing question in SO

Comment: @Nikhil Check my answer to see if is that what you want. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

**--EDITED--**

Now you can only highlight in a straight way (up or down).
Probably there is a more elegant way to do all of this but i think this will works as you want

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vrW2n/9/

```
// Add this variable    
var lastRow = 0;
```

In `mousedown()`:

```
    // This line gets the index of the first clicked row.
    lastRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;

    active = true;
    $(".csstdhighlight").removeClass("csstdhighlight"); // clear previous selection

    //This is the big trick
    $(".temp_selected").removeClass("temp_selected");
...
```

And in `mousemove()`:

```
...
    /* Begin my edit
    Compares the actual 'mousemove' row index
    with the last and next row index
    */
    var thisRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;

    if( lastRow == thisRow || lastRow == thisRow - 1 || lastRow == thisRow + 1 ){
        lastRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
    }else
        return;
    // End my edit
...
```

Comment: hi void i have one problem in ur solution

Comment: void:when i start dragging of cell zigzag move mouse like Z then cell selection happens.how to make selection straight way.

Comment: @Nikhil You need only a line by line selection ?

Comment: void how to check if span contain text or not "$cell.find('span').text"

Comment: @Nikhil, you can try something like this: `if( $('.teste').text().length === 0 )`

Comment: @Nikhil, Oh, i'm sorry, `if( $('yourSelector').text().length === 0 )`, 'teste' is 'test' in portuguese, i was testing here ^^'

Comment: ohhh nice.. void i am checking if in table previous cell or next cell there span tag have text then make color yellow with rowspan

Comment: void:if span is found then how to find its current row

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12571/discussion-between-void-and-nikhil)