# how to make cell selection row by row not zigzag way

Tags: jquery, html, css

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrW2n/4/)

I want to drag the mouse on cell and whatever is under cells gets selected.
only its under cell  get selected.
if user moves mouse zigzag way then no selection be happen. How can i do that.
.
[image: below image shows how can i drag correct way over table cell]

***above image show correct way of flow***

Comment: Maybe you can try canceling the drag action when the mouse cursor don't go exactly to the next second <td> of the next <tr> of your current position. I believe this can be done.

Comment: Murifo:ca u show me in fiddle how its possible

Comment: I don't really know how to do this, but i can give it a try.

Comment: use mousehover to detect mouse moved from selected and deselect cell

Comment: japanpro:can u show me in fiddle how it possible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998126/disabling-click-on-minute-cell/

I hope it helps ^^'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution from the posted jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ajj2h/

Instead of highlighting based on each item that has been moused over, we can look at the index of the first (being the one clicked) and the last (being the one currently hovered with an active click drag state) and highlight all cells between.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-know-on-which-element-an-item-is-currently-being-dragged-on/) topic. i think this will help you to know on which element an item is currently being dragged on